# Runuser command not working on startup in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu-18.04

I've created a startup script which uses `runuser` command to get the `usersitepackages` of python3. This works fine when `sudo /etc/init.d/myservice start`, but not on device booting time.

```
USER_NAME=$(if [ $(whoami) = "root" ]; then echo $SUDO_USER; else echo $USER; fi)
if [ $(whoami) = "root" ]; then
  PKG_ROOT=$(runuser -l $USER_NAME -c "python3 -c 'import site; print(site.getusersitepackages())'")
  CELERY_BIN=$(runuser -l $USER_NAME -c "which celery")
  USER_HOME="/home/$USER_NAME"
else
  PKG_ROOT=$(python3 -c 'import site; print(site.getusersitepackages())')
  CELERY_BIN=$(which celery)
  USER_HOME=$(echo $HOME)
fi
```

I want the $PKG_ROOT like `/home/<user_name>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` but I always get the `/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. Also the $USER_NAME can't be used.

Comment: Probably the preffered way is to use `sudo` or `su` from coreutils. Try it with `sudo`. `$(echo $HOME)` is just `$HOME`. What does it mean that it "does not work fine on device booting time"? How do you know it is not working fine? What does that mean? How are you running the script "on device booting time"?

Comment: The init scripts under `/etc/init.d` will be ran when device is booting up. It will be automatic. I will start the service(probably a python script), using this shell script. After the device bootup, we can check you know, whether the service is running or not with `ps - ef | grep python3`.

Comment: Use systemd service file nowadays.